# resume avplayer after destroying the controller

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer, swift4

I have a static AVPlayer for audio playback, I need to make sure that after the controller is destroyed and the audio is replayed, the audio continues to play. I have been trying for several months to resolve this issue but all without any success, 3 months ago I was asked a question on this topic so far there are no answers, please help to solve this issue once and for all

[image]

This is my code:

```
class ViewControllerAudioDetail: UIViewController {

  static var avPlayer = AVPlayer()
  static var status = false
  var timeSlider = false
  fileprivate let seekDuration: Float64 = 10
  fileprivate let seekDurationThirty: Float64 = 30
  var sliderEndTime:Any!
  var sliderDurationTime:Any!



  var mod = [Modal]()

  @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!

  @IBOutlet weak var startTime: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var endTime: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var sliderSong: UISlider!
  @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var Volume: UISlider!
  @IBOutlet weak var iconChange: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

  name.text = mod[thisSong].AudioName
  ImageView.image = mod[0].ImageViewAudio

  player(urlSong:mod[thisSong].UrlName!)

  self.timeSlider = true
  ViewControllerAudioDetail.status = true
  Status()
}  


   @IBAction func sliderSong(_ sender: UISlider) {

      //перемотка аудиозвука
      let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer!.currentItem!.asset.duration)
      let value = sliderSong.value
      let durationToSeek = Float(duration) * value

      ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(Float64(durationToSeek),ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer!.currentItem!.duration.timescale)) { [](state) in


        if (self.iconChange.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "Play.png")))! {
            ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer?.pause()
        } else if (self.iconChange.currentImage?.isEqual(UIImage(named: "Pause.png")))!{
            ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer?.play()
        }
    }
 }









func Status(){

    timeSlider = false

    if ViewControllerAudioDetail.status == true {
    iconChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: .normal)
    ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.play()

    } else {

    iconChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: .normal)
    ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.pause()
  }

}


@IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {


  if ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.rate == 0 && ViewControllerAudioDetail.status == false{
      ViewControllerAudioDetail.status = true
      ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.play()
      ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.rate = 1.0
      iconChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Pause.png"), for: .normal)


      if timeSlider == false {

      sliderDurationTime = ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: nil, using: {
            (CMTime) -> Void in

            self.updateProgressBar()
        })

    }


  } else {

    ViewControllerAudioDetail.status = false
    ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.rate = 0.0
    ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.pause()
    iconChange.setImage(UIImage(named:"Play.png"), for: .normal)

  }

}




 func player(urlSong:String) {

    let url = URL(string: urlSong)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)

    ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)


NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)

sliderDurationTime = ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1), queue: nil, using: {
    (CMTime) -> Void in

    self.updateProgressBar()
})

 sliderEndTime = ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] (time) in

    let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds((ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration))
    self?.sliderSong.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(time)) / Float(duration)

}


  let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.currentItem!.asset.duration)
  let minutesTextOut = Int(duration) / 60 % 60
  let secondsTextOut = Int(duration) % 60
  let strDuration = String(format:"%02d:%02d", minutesTextOut, secondsTextOut)
  endTime.text = strDuration

}


func updateProgressBar(){
    let timeNow = Int(ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.currentTime().value) / Int(ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer.currentTime().timescale)

  let minutesText = timeNow / 60
  let secondsText = timeNow % 60

  let duration = String(format:"%02d:%02d", minutesText, secondsText)
  startTime.text = duration

}
```

Comment: What you mean with: "audio is replayed, the audio continues to play" ?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini when I pass to the controller the second time the audio should continue. i added gif

Comment: So how can the sound continue, if you stop it destroying the static instance inside the call: `player(urlSong:mod[thisSong].UrlName!)` ?. Look inside... I can see this: `ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)`, so you may want change the logic, since `viewDidLoad` will be invoked anytime you create+show a new ViewController. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini you're right

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini but how to make it so that when the user selects another song the player starts playing the song that they just picked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you might have a static variable `playerDidInit` used as a guard, then switch `true` such var the first time you are going to initialize the `AVPlayer`. To be able to init it again, in case you want to change your `currentSong`, then you may do something like:

```
static var playerDidInit = false
static var currentSong:String?
//....//

func player(urlSong:String) {
  if !playerDidInit || urlSong != currentSong {
  playerDidInit = true
  currentSong = urlSong

  let url = URL(string: urlSong)
  let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
  ViewControllerAudioDetail.avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
}
```

Comment: I probably did not correctly explain (I have a bad English so  I use an interpreter) I updated the question

Comment: @Vasya2014 check the answer

Comment: thanks it works fine and the last question if you do not mind What should I use for save data, NotificationCenter?

Comment: @Vasya2014 `NotificationCenter` cannot be not used for such purpose. It can be used for sending/observing different kind of notifications. About the question: "use for save data?", it depends by which kind of data you have to save?

Comment: data about the player such as listening time, track name, track number

Comment: @Vasya2014 You may look at `UserDefaults` for the easy solution. But if you have to store many/complex things better use `CoreData`